# ZMQ Error: zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied

Tags: python-3.x, pyzmq

So i am making a zmq chat app, it worked before but now it isnt. It throws up the error

```
zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
```

In the server program.

I have not turned on any firewalls etc.
Here is the server code:

```
import time
import zmq 
import tkinter as tk
import threading

port = "8080" 
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)


HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Server")
root.geometry("500x500")

def SM():
   value = str(entry.get())
   T.insert(tk.END, """
   You: """+value)
   socket.send_string(value)

def Receive():
   global T
   while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    message = socket.recv_string()
    print(message)
    T.insert(tk.END, """
    Them: """+ str(message))
    time.sleep(0.1)
def Kick():
    print("Kicked")
    socket.send_string("Kicked!")


x = threading.Thread(target=Receive)


frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
v = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')

frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

frame_2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
frame_2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')
frame3 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
frame3.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')
T = tk.Text(frame,x=0.5, y=0.8, width=100, height=30, yscrollcommand=v.set)
T.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(frame_2, font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

v.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
button = tk.Button(frame_2, text="Send Message", font=40,command=SM)
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)
button2 = tk.Button(frame3, text="Kick this client", font=40,command=Kick)
button2.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)
v.config(command=T.yview)
x.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Whats funny is that it suddenly started throwing the error. It worked before, but doesnt now...

Answer (score -1):

> **Q** : *"It worked before, but doesnt now..."*

From the as-is code, you pay no efforts to defend your application against common problems it meets throughout its lifecycle.

No error checking of return values.

No error resilience attempts like common in `try: ... except: ... finally:`

No ZeroMQ defensive configurations present.

No `.connect()`-ed peer visible, so a claim "it worked" is excluded from a repeatable MCVE-based re-inspection.

### Remedies ?

Start using explicit testing of return-values, start re-factoring the code into the `try: ... except: ... finally:` error-isolation & error-remedy blocks.

Also start defending your ZeroMQ resources :

```
socket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 ) # ALWAYS, RIGHT AFTER INSTANTIATION TOOK PLACE
#                                  # ALWAYS EXPLICITLY (Zero-warranty on API version)
```

and add, best into the Tk or at least into the interpreter exit handler, all the respective explicit terminations :

```
...
try:
     socket.close()

except:
     pass # log or print any EXC-case here, as needed

finally:
     context.term()
```

Not doing so may easily leave a forever hanging resource ( most probably `.bind()`-blocking orphan(s) ) from previous code runs. A reboot may easily prove this hung-orphan(s) to have been a case.

Comment: not what was asked... the question was not about advice how to hadle return value and how to process error response... not you d* bussuness... don't know the answer - don't make one